# I can't get PHP to show/work on GoDaddy

Tags: php

I have checked countless sites on how to get this to fix but these are older versions of godaddy.

When I put PHP in an HTML file on godaddy, the PHP will not load but the HTML will.

```
<?php
echo 'Hi - PHP';
?>
<html>
<head>
<p>Hi - HTML</p>
</head>
</html>
```

The outcome is:
Hi - HTML

Nothing more.

Whenever I try to load a .php file on my site, I just get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Any help?

-And yes, I have checked stackoverflow multiple times.

Comment: err.... `.php` extension?

Comment: Sorry, yes. .php extension

Comment: So, what? Either you get "Hi - HTML", or you get a 500 error. Which is it? Have you checked the source view in the browser whether you see the PHP code in there or not?

Comment: PHP just doesn't work. Yes it shows up in the source code.